# Calling Azure COSMOS DB Table API functions (c#) form Azure function trigger(c#)

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I want to create table from Azure Function trigger of Document DB.But it always give error "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." any one can help to resolve this issue?

```
    #r "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client"
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using  System.Net;
public static async Task Run(IReadOnlyList<Document> input, TraceWriter log)
{

string connectionString = "<connection string copied from portal>";
            try
            {
                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
                CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
                CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("testtable");
                bool f = table.CreateIfNotExists();
            }

            catch (StorageException e)
            {
                log.Info(e.InnerException.Message);
            }

}
```

function.json

```
{
    {
        "bindings": [{
            "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
            "name": "input",
            "direction": "in",
            "leaseCollectionName": "leases",
            "connectionStringSetting": "personsTrigger_ConnectionString",
            "databaseName": "document-temp",
            "collectionName": "persons",
            "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": true
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: I see a lot of code which is 'unnecessary' when using the proper triggers. Can you show us the contents of the `function.json` file? Also, have a look the tutorial (if you haven't already) where they also create a Cosmos DB trigger: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function Also, where are you receiving this 400 status? In the App Insights, monitoring, somewhere else?

Comment: function.json {{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
      "name": "input",
      "direction": "in",
      "leaseCollectionName": "leases",
      "connectionStringSetting": "personsTrigger_ConnectionString",
      "databaseName": "document-temp",
      "collectionName": "persons",
      "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": true
    }
  ]
}

Comment: This is simple trigger function on Document DB .created via azure portal.I have write only code to create Table in Cosmos Table API

Comment: I assume the `personsTrigger_ConnectionString` with a correct value is also added to the application settings in the Azure Portal?

Comment: Connection string of Table API?

Comment: Can you share your connection string? Please remove account name/key with some dummy data in there before sharing.

Comment: This is string with dummy values .                                                           
string connectionString = DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=dummytable;AccountKey=uwiuweiuweiuweiuweiweuweuiyieeyiyeowu;TableEndpoint=<table url>